# .execute("INSERT gives OperationalError: unable to open database file

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

So i'm creating a password manager and for some reason, whenever I'm using classes, I can't input any data into my database when using SQL. (Note: When using tkinter I can still use SQL to input code into my database)

I've already connected to the database in the same way I have for the rest of my code

class dataentry():

```
 def __init__(self,master):

      conn = sqlite3.connect('passworddatabase.db')
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords(username STRING,password STRING,portal_name STRING)') #creates tables to be used, incase it does not exist

      self.username=StringVar() #creates tkinter variable, and validates contents of what will be entered
      self.password=StringVar() #""
      self.portal_name=StringVar() #""

      self.master=master
      self.master.geometry('400x200+100+200') #geometry
      self.master.title('Password Manager') #window title

      self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Add New Details', fg='white', bg='black').grid(row=0,column=0)
      self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Username',fg='black').grid(row=3,column=0)
      self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Password',fg='black').grid(row=4,column=0)
      self.label2=Label(self.master,text='Application Name',fg='black').grid(row=5,column=0)

      self.username=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.username).grid(row=3,column=1)
      self.password=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.password,show="*").grid(row=4,column=1) #hides password enteries
      self.portal_name=Entry(self.master,textvariable=self.portal_name).grid(row=5,column=1)
      self.button4=Button(self.master,text="Add Details",fg='white', bg='black', command=self.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=10,column=1) #add's field enteries to database
      self.button5=Button(self.master,text="Return to Home Page",fg='white', bg='black',command=self.exit).grid(row=12,column=1) #exit button
```

#### the code above was to give the subroutine below (responsible for adding the data) some context

```
 def dynamic_data_entry(self):
      global dynamic_data_entry #access within the entire program
    #this is what adds the data to the database
      global conn, cursor
      conn = sqlite3.connect('passworddatabase.db')
      c = conn.cursor()
      username1 = self.username #assigning variables
      password1 = self.password #""
      portal_name1 = self.portal_name #
      c.execute("INSERT INTO passwords(username, password, portal_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(username1, password1, portal_name1)) #enters data into the table
      conn.commit()
      self.writetodatabase() 

 def writetodatabase(self):
      for i in range(1):
           time.sleep(1)
      c.close()
      conn.close()
```

I expected the data to be added to the database table 'passwords' rather it comes up w errors, the notable two being that the database is a 'readonly'

> update: the traceback no longer reports readonly database issue, but reports this:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:\Users\owner\Documents\A-Levels\Subjects\Comp.science\nea\code\loginnew.py", line 80, in dynamic_data_entry
>     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO passwords(username, password, portal_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(username1, password1, portal_name1)) #enters data into the table
> sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
> ```

Comment: `cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords(username STRING,password STRING,portal_name STRING)')` you didn't `conn.commit()` after this.

Comment: And what is the point of `global conn, cursor` when you then immediately do `conn = sqlite3.connect('passworddatabase.db')` but don't go on to define `cursor` in that function? The chain of code is confusing to follow.

Comment: @roganjosh the table is already created anyway. regardless i'm still continually getting a readonly error

Comment: @SalihMSA: You don `.commit` => `cursor.execute('CREATE ...`